# Apply method to literal

Tags: vb.net, linqpad

I am familiar with C#, but not at all with VB and I want to convert a C# example (in LINQPad) into VB:

```cs
if (2 + 2 == 4)
    "True".Dump();
```

I came up with the following working VB code:

```vb
Dim word = "True"
If 2 + 2 = 4 Then
    word.Dump
End If
```

Now, why could I not just write the following instead ?

```vb
If 2 + 2 = 4 Then
    "True".Dump  ' BC30035 Syntax error
End If
```

It seems like I cant apply a method to a litteral in VB and I must store it in a variable prior,
but surely I must be missing something here... no ?

P.S. Parentheses around the string are not working any better.

Comment: I don't use LinqPad but you can absolutely do that in Visual Studio.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Are you sure? I can make it work with `CStr("True").Dump()`, but not with the plain literal in `"True".Dump()`. Similarly for an extension method on integers, `CInt(2).Foo()` works but `2.Foo()` wants to regard the `2` as a line number and complains that it needs to be followed by a colon.

Comment: @AndrewMorton IIRC you can if you use `Call`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph jmcilhinney covered that in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66118469/1115360). I was just looking throught the VB.NET language spec, and it looks like the [Statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/reference/language-specification/statements) section covers it, if anyone else is interested: "The Microsoft Visual Basic Compiler only allows statements which start with a keyword or an identifier."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is not that you cannot call a method on a literal. The issue is you cannot begin a line of code with a literal, much as you cannot begin a line of code with the `New` keyword. If you do this:

```vb
Dim x = "Hello".Split("l"c)
Dim y = 2.ToString()
```

it works without issue. If you do this:

```vb
"Hello".Split("l"c)
2.ToString()
```

you get two errors and, in both cases, mousing over the issue tells you:

> Only member access expression can start an invocation statement.

Just as if you wanted to start a line with a constructor, you can use the `Call` keyword to effectively do what you want:

```vb
Call "Hello".Split("l"c)
Call 2.ToString()
```